# Generic Point Addition in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to pimp the Tuple(2) class with addition and scala multiplication members, so that I can use them more easily as geometric 2D points. This is what I've got:

```
implicit class Point[+T: Numeric](val t: (T, T)) {
  import Numeric.Implicits._
  def _1 = t._1
  def _2 = t._2

  def +[V >: T](p: Point[V])(implicit ev: Numeric[V]) : (V,V) = 
    (ev.plus(t._1, p._1), ev.plus(t._2, p._2))
}

println((2, 3) + Point(5.0, 6.0))
```

This doesn't work (can't find `ev`) presumably because strictly speaking `Float` isn't a supertype of `Int` - but there doesn't actually seem to be a weak-conformance-bound operator, and leaving it out entirely means I can't use `ev.plus` anymore because it's expecting two values of the same type `V`, not one of `T` and one of `V`.

How can I properly implement this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right. The problem is that `Numeric[T]` doesn't allow one to mix types (`V` and `T`) according to it's signature: `def plus(x: T, y: T): T`.

You can either use/emulate this library:
https://github.com/azavea/numeric. It does a lot of implicit gymnastics to allow mixed types to work.

It does exactly what you need:

> EasyImplicits allows you to operate on mixed numeric types (e.g. T + U + Int).

Alternatively chose to use underlying `Double` type instead of `T`/`V` - I know that's not always great (loss of precision, etc).

You code still works with points that don't mix types which is not that bad, otherwise `Double` doesn't look that terrible since automatic conversion will happen anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that because the constructor parameter is a tuple, it complicates what should have been simple numeric widening. This covers many (most?) conversions.

```
implicit class Point[T: Numeric](a: (T, T)) {
  import Numeric.Implicits._
  val _1 = a._1
  val _2 = a._2

  def +(x: T, y: T) = add(_1, _2, x, y)

  def +[U: Numeric](x:U, y:U)(implicit ev: T => U) =
    add[U](ev(_1), ev(_2), x, y)

  def +[U: Numeric](b: Point[U])(implicit ev: T => U) =
    add[U](ev(_1), ev(_2), b._1, b._2)

  private def add[N: Numeric](a:N, b:N, c:N, d:N) = (a+c, b+d)
}
```

usage:

```
(1, 4) + (2.2, 4.4)         //res0: (Double, Double) = (3.2,8.4)
(2.1, 3.1) + (9, 2)         //res1: (Double, Double) = (11.1,5.1)
(1, 4) + Point((5.2, 6.2))  //res2: (Double, Double) = (6.2,10.2)
Point((2, 3)) + (4L, 5L)    //res3: (Long, Long) = (6,8)
Point((1.5, 2.9)) + (1, 1)  //res4: (Double, Double) = (2.5,3.9)
```

But it won't widen the elements of an existing `Point` passed as a parameter to the `+()` method.

```
(3.3, 4.5) + Point((1, 3))  //Error:No implicit view available from Double => Int.
```